# Form action url not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

I am trying to use url in form action without using form helper in codeigniter but it's not working.

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url().'test'; ?>">
<form method="post"  action="/main_controller/test">
```

controller function

```
public function test(){
    echo "test function";
}
```

the error I am getting

http://prntscr.com/eyzhdd

Comment: otherwise set short method name in route file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main_controller/test">
```

as well `base_url()` should define as(`application/config/config.php`)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
                        ^ on the end

$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'; # Line 26 if version 3.0+
```

---

```
<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main_controller/test
              ^            ^           ^           ^
           base URL      index Controller Name   Method name
```

---

Check out the [Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html).

Comment: sorry for accepting it very late, and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url().'/main_controller/test/'; ?>">
```

Use Like this and define base url  in **http://www.example.com/** config.php file

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `base_url()`, you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in `application/config/autoload.php` (around line 67):

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, manually in controller:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then change

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url().'test'; ?>">
```

to

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main_controller/test">
```

Finally add  base url in application/config/config.php. For instance,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs: You can remove index.php from action url with `.htaccess file`. Please read [documenation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to go to the following directory in your Codeigniter project folder;

*your_codeigniter_project_name/application/config/config.php*

and look for the configuration code that looks like;

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

Now confirm that your base URL configuration is pointing to your project directory; if it's a project being worked on your localhost then the link should look like this;

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';
```

---

**Now about the form action;** if you already have a .htacess file in the root directory of your Codeigniter project folder then your form action URL should be written as follows;

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>main_controller/test">
```

And if you don't have .htaccess file in your project root directory then the form action URL should be;

```
<form method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/main_controller/test">
```